# CSS class to modify id?

Tags: css

I'm attempting to style a nav `<li>` element in the same way that I style its active state. When a user is on the page in question, the nav element should have class `.on` in addition to its ID. I'm off somewhere because the page is not cooperating. FYI this is using Thesis, so the body of each page already has the .custom class. Thanks!

**CSS (see panel4a)**

```
/*Navigation*/
.custom div#custom_nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.custom #nav_item {
    width: 224px; height: 360px;
    background: url('images/nav_sprite.png');
    margin: 10px auto; padding: 0;
    position: relative;}

.custom #nav_item li {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;
    position: absolute;}

.custom #nav_item li, #nav_item a {
    display: block;}


.custom #panel1 {top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 224px; height: 30px;}
.custom #panel2 {top: 51px; left: 0px; width: 224px; height: 30px;}
.custom #panel3 {top: 107px; left: 0px; width: 224px; height: 30px;}
.custom #panel4 {top: 162px; left: 0px; width: 224px; height: 30px;}
.custom #panel4a {top: 194px; left: 30px; width: 50px; height: 15px;}
.custom #panel4b {top: 194px; left: 83px; width: 36px; height: 15px;}
.custom #panel4c {top: 194px; left: 123px; width: 27px; height: 15px;}
.custom #panel4d {top: 194px; left: 153px; width: 62px; height: 15px;}
.custom #panel5 {top: 216px; left: 0px; width: 224px; height: 30px;}
.custom #panel6 {top: 268px; left: 0px; width: 224px; height: 30px;}
.custom #panel7 {top: 324px; left: 0px; width: 224px; height: 30px;}

.custom #panel1 a, #panel2 a, #panel3 a, #panel4 a, #panel5 a, #panel6 a, #panel7 a {
    height: 30px;
}

.custom #panel4a a, #panel4b a, #panel4c a, #panel4d a {
    height: 15px;
}

.custom .on #panel4a {
    background: transparent url('images/nav_sprite.png')
    0px -546px no-repeat;}}

.custom #panel1 a:hover {
    background: transparent url('images/nav_sprite.png')
    0px -384px no-repeat;}
.custom #panel2 a:hover {
    background: transparent url('images/nav_sprite.png')
    0px -435px no-repeat;}
.custom #panel3 a:hover {
    background: transparent url('images/nav_sprite.png')
    0px -491px no-repeat;}
.custom #panel4 a:hover {
    background: transparent url('images/nav_sprite.png')
    0px -546px no-repeat;}
.custom #panel4a a:hover {
    background: transparent url('images/nav_sprite.png')
    -30px -578px no-repeat;}
.custom #panel4b a:hover {
    background: transparent url('images/nav_sprite.png')
    -83px -578px no-repeat;}
.custom #panel4c a:hover {
    background: transparent url('images/nav_sprite.png')
    -123px -578px no-repeat;}
.custom #panel4d a:hover {
    background: transparent url('images/nav_sprite.png')
    -153px -578px no-repeat;}
.custom #panel5 a:hover {
    background: transparent url('images/nav_sprite.png')
    0px -600px no-repeat;}
.custom #panel6 a:hover {
    background: transparent url('images/nav_sprite.png')
    0px -652px no-repeat;}
.custom #panel7 a:hover {
    background: transparent url('images/nav_sprite.png')
    0px -708px no-repeat;}
```

**CODE (see panel4a)**

```
function custom_nav() { ?>
    <ul id="nav_item">
        <li id="panel1"><a href="<?php bloginfo(url)?>"></a></li>
        <li id="panel2"><a href="<?php bloginfo(url)?>/tools"></a></li>
        <li id="panel3"><a href="<?php bloginfo(url)?>/sales"></a></li>
        <li id="panel4"><a href="<?php bloginfo(url)?>/portfolio_identity"></a></li>
        <li id="panel4a" class="<?php if (is_page('portfolio_identity')) {echo 'on';} else {echo 'panel4a';} ?>"><a href="<?php bloginfo(url)?>/portfolio_identity"></a></li>
        <li id="panel4b"><a href="<?php bloginfo(url)?>/portfolio_print"></a></li>
        <li id="panel4c"><a href="<?php bloginfo(url)?>/portfolio_web"></a></li>
        <li id="panel4d"><a href="<?php bloginfo(url)?>/portfolio_packaging"></a></li>
        <li id="panel5"><a href="<?php bloginfo(url)?>/awards"></a></li>
        <li id="panel6"><a href="<?php bloginfo(url)?>/contact"></a></li>
        <li id="panel7"><a href="<?php bloginfo(url)?>/client_login"></a></li>
    </ul>
<?php }
add_action('thesis_hook_before_sidebar_1', 'custom_nav');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the correct selector order:

```
ul#nav_item #panel4a.on { /** specific styles **/ }
```

note this is grossly over-specific; and just

`#panel4a.on` should suffice however.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to do:

```
.custom #panel4a.on {/*do some custom active styling*/}
```

This will select the element with both the id of `panel4a` and the `on` class.

Answer (score 0):

The `.on` class is not inside the `#panel4a` `li` element.. it is on the same element (one ``` id`` the other class ```)

so the rule should be

```
.custom #panel4a.on {
    background: transparent url('images/nav_sprite.png') 0px -546px no-repeat;
}
```

(*removed the double `}` at the end as well..*)